# Multiple file uploading In Reacjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, react-fullstack

I want to upload the multiple images in react but when i pass the object with  formdata.append it give the result of images: ["[object File],[object File],[object File]"] instead of images Array
here is my code

```
  for (let key of Object.keys(body)) {
        formdata.append(key, body[key]);
    }
```

here body is the data object [object which i pass in formdata.append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEVo9.jpg)which I pass with  formdata.append[result which i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch6sm.jpg)  so how should be solve this issue

[image]

Comment: How is it related to mean-stack?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. This is what happens when you upload multiple images. It returns them in an array. You have to map through this array to get every single image